# Regular Expression for number with range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was playing with regular expression and noticed that the below code is returning `true`. Can any one explain why?

```js
console.log(/\d{4,12}$/.test('12345678901234567890'));
```

How can I have limited number of digits say, 4-8(number of digits) and some alphabets in my regular expression? Ex- ('abc7896' -> true, 'a78b96' -> true, etc)

Comment: please add some use cases and the wanted results

Comment: @anubhava Can you help me in figuring out the second part of question?

Comment: ` 4-8(number of digits) and some alphabets` is unclear. You need to clarify with more examples.

Comment: Added some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments and edits in your question, you may use this regex:

```
/^(?:[a-z]*\d){4,8}[a-z]*$/gim
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLgzbO/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^            - Start
(?:          - Start non-capturing group
   [a-z]*\d  - Match 0 or more alphabets followed by a digit
){4,8}       - End non-capturing group. [4,8} matches it 4 to 8 times
[a-z]*       - Match trailing 0 or more alphabets in input
$            - End
```

**Flags:**

```
g - Global search
i - Ignore case Match
m - Multiline mode
```

Comment: Please explain the regex. Especially `(?:[a-z]*\d){4,8}`.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{4,12}` looks if the string *contains* 4 to 12 digits which is correct. If you want to limit this, you can use the anchor tags - `^` for beginning and `$` for end of string like this:

`^\d{4,12}$` or respectively `/^\d{4,12}$/`

Now from the beginning to the end of the string, only 4 to 12 characters can appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the characters `^` and `$` at the start and at the end of your pattern. Doing so you state that you are looking for a string that starts with a digit and it can have any number of digits from 4 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there are 4 to 12 digits in the string with some non digits inbetween.

```js
console.log(/^\D*(\d\D*){4,12}$/.test('a78b96'));
console.log(/^\D*(\d\D*){4,12}$/.test('a786'));
console.log(/^\D*(\d\D*){4,12}$/.test('a1234567890123'));
```